# Delta between two visuals in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables.  Table one is yesterday's data and Table 2 is today's data.  Visual 1 is a visual based on Table 1 and Visual 2 is a visual based on Table 2.  These two visuals are identical in terms of their layout and filters.  I have been tasked to create a 3rd visual which is the delta between the numbers in the two visuals.  What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question... (not that there's something wrong with that or anything)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the relationship between the tables, but assuming the tables are basically identical and have a 1-to-1 relationship you would just use `='Table2'[ColumnX]-'Table1'[ColumnX]`

Comment: Thanks.  So then looks like it can't be done at visual level and has to be done at the table data level.  Do I create a 3rd table to add the formula or do I add it to one of the tables?

Comment: You could create a 3rd table, but I personally would just add it as a calculated column to one of the existing tables. Alternatively, I believe it could just be done as a metric and then you can add that metric to a new or existing visual.